# Phpstorm + xdebug = Process finished with exit code 255

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm

I have just installed PHPStorm and configured xDebug in my XAMPP php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Restarted apache, clicked "Debug" in PHPStorm and I have this error in the console:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 C:/Users/Myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration C:\pwt\pwt-new
Testing started at 2:17 PM ...

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Googling says there is something wrong with phpunit but I have no idea what.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Check your PHP's error log for some hints. It could be anything -- missing files; PHP misconfiguration (missing extension etc); PHP error (segfault). P.S. You may also run PHPUnit tests via Debug button and actually debug PHPUnit code to see where it fails.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?